# How to style text of submit button

Tags: html, css

I have a link styled as follows:

```
<style>
  .addNew{
    background-color: #FFF;
    display: block;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    color: #08c;
    border:3px dashed #08c;
    cursor: pointer;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    font-size: 1em;
  }
</style>
    <a class='addNew'>
            <i class="fa fa-plus" ></i> Add new 
            <span style='text-decoration:underline'>Object</span>
    </a>
```

I am using a span-tag inside the text and a [font-awesome icon](http://fontawesome.io/).
How can I use this for an submit button? I tried this:

```
<input type='submit' class='addNew' value="Add new Object">
```

But I have no idea how to style the text of the submit button.
[image]

Comment: Presumably the `</i>` close tag should be after the **Add new** text in the question and in the answer below?

Comment: @clayRay guess its  a design question :)

Comment: oh, is there a pseudo element in the `.fa-plus` class that adds the + symbol? In that case that works fine. I just couldn't work out what the `<i>..` would do.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Use a [button element](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button).

```
<button class='addNew'>
        <i class="fa fa-plus" ></i> Add new 
        <span style='text-decoration:underline'>Object</span>
</button>
```

… then you can have child elements and target them independently for styling.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `<button>`

```
<button><i class="fa fa-plus"> Add new <span style="text-decoration:underline;">Object</span></button>
```

> Button behaviour is different then `<input type="button">` or `<input type="submit">`. You can append elements in `<button>`.

Comment: Thank you. But what do you mean with that the behaviour is different? According to http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.5 the default behavior of a button is equivalent to ' type=submit'.

Comment: With behaviour i means the coding behaviour not the functionality. If you use `<input type="submit">` then you will enter the text in `value` which does not support any child element but in button you can add child element.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `<button>` tag for submit. You need to also give the button a type of `submit` to capture the browser event.

```
<button type="submit">
    <a>link</a>
    <span>span</span>
</button>
```

**EDIT**: Why you should specify `type` of submit

```
<form>
    <input />
    <button type="button">not a submit button</button>
    <button type="submit">submit button</button>
</form>
```

In this case, anyone looking at your code will know exactly which `<button>` is the actually submit button in a second. Also, if someone is going to get the form's submit button with CSS selector, one can easily do so by `button[type="submit"]`. Yes `submit` is the default type, but it is also the better practice for readability and easier for debugging.

Comment: "You can also use `<button>` tag for submit" — Your the third person to say that. "You need to also give the button a type of submit" — Wrong. Submit is the default value for the type attribute.

Comment: If you are going to place multiple `<button>` inside a form, it's the best practice to specify `type` of `submit`.

Comment: — No it isn't. `submit` is the default type and having multiple button elements doesn't change that. Adding it just bloats the code. (I'd accept that it could make it clearer if you are mixing different button types in the form, but that doesn't seem to be the case here).