# How to add word-wrap css property to this element?

Tags: css

I am trying to style this HTML element with word-wrap CSS property, but its Value (host rewards document) is printed on the site, so how can add style to this element?

```
<input type="submit" name="ctl00$BaseBody$ctl00$ctl01$Category$ctl00$CategoryNames" value="host rewards document" id="ctl00_BaseBody_ctl00_ctl01_Category_ctl00_CategoryNames" class="btn btn-link CategoryNameClass">
```

[image]

Comment: Use class "CategoryNameClass" for writing css

Comment: Also it will need a `max-width`.

Comment: it's easy ... you cannot

Comment: The 'duplicate' mark is incorrect - the question IS duplicate, but not with the one that's marked (that one talks about text/textarea elements). For a button, there's another question that has the correct answer:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37183114/how-to-style-text-of-submit-button

Answer (score -1):

I would simply use:

`style="word-wrap:break-word"`

Comment: It doesn't work

Comment: I have to say that specific comes from ASP.NET cshtml. Maybe you just have to tweak a bit or so, but `style=""`should work, you just have to figure out the specific keyword for the word wrapping for the environment you are in